# Building dll without statically linking

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dll

I've got project A and project B as part of a solution. Project A is dependent on project B, because it uses classes from project B. The easiest way to build a dll, is to put the two together, and build one dll out of that. Now assume, Project B gets updated every week or so.
Because of those regular updates, I would prefer to just build a dll for project A and use the source code of project B in the solution. So is there a way to achieve this, to build a dll and reference the "missing" files (files from project B) without statically linking them?
Note: I want project B to stay as source code and not be a dll

Comment: No, what you're asking is not possible. Project A needs the Project B's dll. You cannot reference a project that isn't built.

Comment: if you replace **A** & **B** with some demo source **code**, we can understand better what you want

Answer (score 1):

Yes - use a "Project Reference" in Visual Studio - it will update your build process so Project A is built after Project B, and Project A will also always have the latest IntelliSense on Project B.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wkze6zky(v=vs.120).aspx

Comment: Would the dll of project A then work in a solution with only.the source code of project B or does your solution only works if project B is also built to a dll?

Comment: @user3125470 Project References *require* the source-code of the parent project - that's why it's a Project Reference and not an Assembly Reference (the two are mutually exclusive and are alternative to each other - though in the end a Project References results in an assembly-reference after the parent project is built).